# Why do I get AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'average_neighbor_in_degree'?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, attributeerror, directed-graph

I have networkx v.2.3 and I need to compute the average neighbor degree of the nodes of a directed graph. Why is the method is not being recognized?

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_path([0,1,2,3])
nx.average_neighbor_in_degree(G)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `average_neighbor_in_degree` method was replaced in networkx 1.6 - see [release notes](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/api_1.6.html) (thanks @Delena Malan).

This functionality is available in networkx 2.3 with the [`average_neighbor_degree`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.3/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.assortativity.average_neighbor_degree.html) method using the `target` & `source` keyword arguments:

**Code:**

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_path([0,1,2,3])
print(nx.average_neighbor_degree(G, source='in', target='in'))
```

**Output:**

```
{0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 0.0}
```